# jQuery and selectors in use with specific span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, html-manipulation

### jQuery selector

#### Selecting specific span tags

I had this problem with jQuery's selector. It was a problem for hours. It could not select that specific span tag that I wanted to manipulate and that's why I'm stuck scratching my head with this one.

My goal was to add different classes for each span tag that had different style values.
Thus I almost succeeded I couldn't figure out how to add different classes to each span tag, so I ended up clueless.

I basically want the span with font-size of 180% to be in a specific class doesn't matter which really cause I can change that later if the code works. The other span tag with font-size of 100% should also have a class, the other class. I hope you get more clarity in what I'm trying to do now at least that's what I'm hoping for.

The code exists in the link below, feel free to post a fix and optionally but not required a explaination of why it didn't work! thank you.

jQuery Submission: [JS Bin Post](http://jsbin.com/ipocos/2/edit)

Here's the code itself aswell.

```
    var val1 = "font-size: 180%";
    var val2 = "font-size: 100%";
    var title = $("span").attr("style");
    
    $(function(){
    if ($("span:contains('font-size: 100%')")) {
      $('span').addClass("text_shadow2");
      if ($('span').has("text_shadow1")) {
         $('span').removeClass("text_shadow1");
      }
    }
        if ($("span:contains('font-size: 180%')")) {
           $('span').addClass("text_shadow1");
           if ($('span').has("text_shadow2")) {
               $('span').removeClass("text_shadow2");
           }
        }
        },function(){
        if ($("span:contains('font-size: 100%')")) {
        $('span').addClass("text_shadow2");
        if ($('span').has("text_shadow1")) {
              $('span').removeClass("text_shadow1");
           }
        }
        if ($("span:contains('font-size: 180%')")) {
        $('span').addClass("text_shadow1");
            if ($('span').has("text_shadow2")) {
               $('span').removeClass("text_shadow2");
               }
        }
    });

    if ($(val1==title)) {alert("1. "+title);} 
    if ($(val2==title)) {alert("2. "+title);}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you expect the code to do.

Comment: You have to say what specific `<span>` you need help with selecting.

Comment: `:contains` only examines text in the element, not styles.

Comment: I've tried the .attr() from jQuery but it can't check for a value, strangely. And the hasAttr jQuery plugin is gone can't find it anywhere. I heard it was good. I need a workaround for this however.

I'm not a expert in any way, but this is as far as I could do sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to parse the style attribute. Browsers aren't going to set the font-size property to a percentage but will do the calcs instead

```
$('span').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('style').match('180%');
}).addClass('someClass');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AbZBD/

Comment: It seems that I really am not allowed to express myself on certain pages? dictatorship on the highest level. Why are some people this evil to me?



I posted valid feedback, what is this? I really dislike how everything is handled on this site you should be ashamed of yourselves really. I'll leave this pathetic website, GOOD BYE!